# Trigger for control background not firing when color is in hexadecimal

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, background, hex

Let's say I have 3 buttons in my window:

```
<Button Content="Green Button" Background="LimeGreen" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
<Button Content="Red Button" Background="Red" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
<Button Content="Hex Button" Background="#FF32CD32" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
```

In app.xaml I created a style which will be used by all buttons:

```
<Application.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                    <Border Name="border"
                        BorderThickness="1.5"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.9" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="DarkOrange" />
                        </MultiTrigger>

                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="Background" Value="LimeGreen" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Chartreuse" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

For the first two buttons, everything works perfectly. However, when I try to click the third button, nothing happens.
Even if I add another multitrigger with condition "Background value="#FF32CD32" (which should be the same as LimeGreen), it changes nothing.

Does hexadecimal values even work with triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after gaining a little more experience with WPF, I decided to give it one more shot. Answer came almost immediately...

The problem is, values provided in conditions are being read as Colors. XAML alone can't resolve their RGB representation. Let's see on example:

If the background color is Red (which is already defined in Colors/Brushes enum), value is being read correctly. However, if the value provided is, let's say, #FFABCDEF, it's also a color, but it's not defined as standard color. For XAML it's just a plain string. Thus, by providing hexadecimal value instead of predefined enum, trigger will fail.

Solution for this is to create custom converter. It will convert color value to its corresponding string representation. Then, when we check the value in the condition, converter will provide us valid string.

### Solution:

First I created converter which returns valid hexadecimal value of color:

```
public class ColorToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Color c = (value as SolidColorBrush).Color;

        return c.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then, in your styling file, include the namespace of created converter:

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:ButtonTest.Converters"
```

In styling file resources (in this case, it was just App.xaml):

```
<conv:ColorToStringConverter x:Key="ColorToStringConverter" />
```

And finally, the triggers:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.9" />
</Trigger>

<!-- Custom colors handling there -->
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Background, Converter={StaticResource ColorToStringConverter}}" Value="#FF32CD32" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Chartreuse" />
</MultiDataTrigger>

<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="DarkOrange" />
</MultiTrigger>

<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="Background" Value="LimeGreen" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Chartreuse" />
</MultiTrigger>
```

Keep an eye on the triggers precedence: hex ones should be declared before standard colors. In my example, #FF32CD32 is the same as LimeGreen, so if I have put it in the end, it would overwrite the standard trigger.